# Clustering of 3 dimensions set of points

Tags: python, neural-network, cluster-analysis

I got a set of points extracted from a movie showing a ball trajectory.
Each point has its coordinates (x,y) corresponding to the ball's position in the image extracted from the movie, and a z coordinate corresponding to the time frame.
The final representation below is the sum of all extracted points frame after frame, rendered in the same 3D graph.

[image]

And here is a picture of how it looks like without the "time" data :
it is the camera standpoint.

[image]

Issue is that I captured as well some movement from the player in the background (but since it is a flat image, the coordinates does not give this information that the player is in the background) and even some other balls on another field in the back !
But when you give a look in 3 dimensions of all these points, you can still identify very clearly what is the trajectory of the main ball, and what is the noise (the player's movement, the other ball in a game field behind, etc...)

I would like to be able to cluster these (x, y, timestamp) points to remove the noise.
But the tools I've used so far are not giving any results : meanshift, DBSCAN are not working. Self-Organizing Maps or Kohonen network neither.
what ever parameters change I bring, the result is not satisfying at all.

Do you have any idea why the way I'm doing it is not giving expected results ? Is there a more appropriate way to cluster 3D data ?

Here is the set of data that I've extracted from the movie:

http://arbalette.hopto.org/images/forums/shoot_prise_8_objets_detectes.json

The picture posted

[image]

is the shoot number 2, but you have 10 shoots.
each detected objet (the ball, and the noise) are in "objets" object, X, Y are the coordinates, and frameNb is the time (the z axis in my picture)

What I've tried, for example with DBSCAN, is the following:

```py
with open("objets_detectes.json") as json_file:
    objets = json.load(json_file)

for shoot in objets:
    positions_spatiales = []    
    for objet in objets[shoot]["objets"]:
        point = [objets[shoot]["objets"][objet]["x"], objets[shoot]["objets"][objet]["y"], objets[shoot]["objets"][objet]["frameNb"]]
        positions_spatiales.append(point)

    positions_spatiales = np.array(positions_spatiales)
    #DBSCAN
    dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=30, min_samples=10)
    clusters = dbscan.fit_predict(positions_spatiales)
    unique_clusters = np.unique(clusters)
```

and then, I plot it with matplotlib to see the result for each shoot, and the failure...

```py
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.title('Tir ' + str(shoot) + ', relation position/temps - analyse du bruit et clustering des points')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    color_indice = 0
    for cluster in unique_clusters:
        x = []
        y = []
        z = []
        cluster_points = positions_spatiales[clusters == cluster]
        for point in cluster_points:
            x.append(point[0])
            y.append(point[1])
            z.append(point[2])

     ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=[replace_by_unique_color_by_cluster], label='Cluster ' + str(cluster), marker='o')

     ax.set_xlabel('X')
     ax.set_ylabel('Y')
     ax.set_zlabel('temps')
     plt.show(block=True)
```

You can see here, plotted, 3 different results with the following parameters : we can clearly see the the main ball's trajectory is not recognised (1 color = 1 recognised cluster).

```py
    dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=30, min_samples=10)
```

with eps = 30:

[image]

```py
    dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=70, min_samples=10)
```

with eps = 70:

[image]

```py
    dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=120, min_samples=10)
```

with eps = 120:

[image]

Comment: would be great if you also share what you have done so far, as well as the data. Since currently, no one can help you further when it comes to the practicle programming part. If you would like to know more about the theory, try crossvalidated

Comment: Asking for recommendations on tools and libraries is explicitly off topic and a reason for questions to be closed.  Please review the question rules and guidelines *before* posting.

Comment: @TinoD you can find the set of data here, under a Json format :

Comment: @Larbalette I'm sorry, but where? You forgot to add a link?

Comment: @TinoD 
http://arbalette.hopto.org/images/forums/shoot_prise_8_objets_detectes.json

You find inside 10 shoots, and under the "objets" sub-part, you'll find all the detected objects (the ball and the noise). x and y are the coordinates. frameNb is the time. It is these coordinates that I've used to render the 3D maps posted above, on shoot number 2.
area data is useless (used to filter the contours detected with cv2.findContours and keep only contours that looks like the ball)

Comment: i guess the comments is not the right way to discuss...it's barely readable :(
I will update my question.

Comment: You can edit it inside your post :D

Comment: @TinoD yes, thank you. That's what I've just done. Hope the issue is now clearer !

Comment: @Larbalette nice job, now you can get proper help and your post is nicely adhering to the rules of how to ask

Comment: @TinoD thanks for your help in this process ! I'm new to stackoverflow, not very easy for the first try ;-) Let's hope some expert will be interested in my question now ! ;-)

Comment: Can you please let me know how you are defining temp? @Larbalette. As it looks like right now, you are doing it with frameNb?

Comment: @TinoD yes, time is defined by the frame number. (assuming you was meaning **time**, and not **temp** ?)

Comment: @Larbalette sorry, mixed up my french and my english there

Comment: How many clusters are you expecting? @Larbalette

Comment: @TinoD I think your answer below, that I need to study shows that you've got it ! 2 clusters : my ball trajectory....and the rest being the noise. your answer looks interesting, let me have a look on it ! Thanks !

Comment: @Larbalette If you have any questions about the approach, comment under the answer, I am still lunching... will edit a bit afterwards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256848/discussion-between-tino-d-and-larbalette).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following answer so far, not great, but it hints that the `eps` and number of points need to be adjusted to get an optimum:

To read the data and packages:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import time

with open("shoot_prise_8_objets_detectes.json") as json_file:
    objets = json.load(json_file)

shoots = []
positions_spatiales = []
x = []
y = []
area = []
frameNumber = []
for shoot in objets:
    for objet in objets[shoot]["objets"]:
        x.append(objets[shoot]["objets"][objet]["x"])
        y.append(objets[shoot]["objets"][objet]["y"])
        area.append(objets[shoot]["objets"][objet]["area"])
        frameNumber.append(objets[shoot]["objets"][objet]["frameNb"])
        shoots.append(shoot)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["shoots", "x", "y", "frame number"])
df["shoots"] = shoots
df["x"] = x
df["y"] = y
df["area"] = area
df["frame number"] = frameNumber
```

The ML part:

```
fig = plt.figure()
for shoot in df["shoots"].unique():
    #print("processing shoot "+str(shoot)+"...")
    subDf = df[df["shoots"] == shoot]
    #print(subDf) # printing
    dataForClustering = subDf[["x","y","frame number"]] # get data for clustering
    scaler = StandardScaler() # scale
    scaledDataForClustering = scaler.fit_transform(dataForClustering) # get scaled data
    #print("_____________________________________________") # niceness
    #print(scaledDataForClustering) # print to check
    # adjust as necessary...
    eps = 0.6 # tested between 0.5 to 1, this seems to be the optimal range
    min_samples = 2 # tested between 1 to 10, 2-5 seems optimal
    dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples, metric="euclidean", algorithm = "ball_tree") # play around with distance and algorithms...
    #print("_____________________________________________")
    clusters = dbscan.fit_predict(scaledDataForClustering) # predict clusters
    clusters_shifted = clusters + 1 # dshit for np.bincount
    cluster_counts = np.bincount(clusters_shifted) # get count of clusters
    most_common_cluster = np.argmax(cluster_counts) # find the cluster with the highest count
    clusters[clusters != most_common_cluster - 1] = -1 # assign all but non most frequent cluster as -1
    clusters[clusters == most_common_cluster - 1] = 1 # assign most frequent cluster as 1
    # till the end is for plotting...
    fig.clf()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    for cluster in np.unique(clusters):
        if cluster == -1:
            label = "noise"
        else:
            label = "ball"
        clusterPoints = subDf[clusters == cluster]
        ax.scatter(clusterPoints['x'], clusterPoints['y'], clusterPoints['frame number'], label=f'Cluster {label}')
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Frame Number')
    ax.set_title('Shoot number: '+str(shoot))
    ax.legend()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.savefig("soccer/shoot"+str(shoot)+".png", dpi = 330)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Short about the approach, I assigned the most common cluster as your signal (non-noise) and everything else as noise. I will improve after lunch.. here are the results so far (for first shoot, all shoots looked similar):

[image: Results for the first shoot]

**V2.0**: after lunch and a coffee, some remarks about my previous answer

The clusters that were generated by DBSCAN were not two, but rather many more, I could see however, that the noise itself was being split into many different clusters, and there was always a cluster that defined the trajectory. Hence, I decided that I needed to identify this cluster and set everything else as noise (-1). This works quite well for some shoots, and for some it is not 100% accurate, however this is to be expected with unsupervised learning on a not so big dataset. Here is one example of this raw clustering with shoot 10:

[image: Raw clusters]

You can see that the trajectory of the ball is nicely clusters, however the noise is being seperated into many small clusters. Ajusting the parameters so this is mitigated (`eps`:  maximum distance between two samples for one to be considered as in the neighborhood of the other) will lead to a worse identification of the ball trajectory. Here are the same results, with the grooping that I mentioned before, with the most common being the ball, and everything else noise:

[image: Reclustered]]

Finally, here are all the results as a gif:

[image: gif]

As you can see, works nice, not for all, but nonetheless acceptable imo

If you have any question about this approach, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks @TinoD
for shoot #1, with 36 objects detected (36 points), with the same parameters than you, eps = 1 and min_samples = 3, I get only one cluster, and not many as you get.
Is it because of the scaling you're doing is pre-treatment ?

Comment: Am in the process of preparing an edit. To answer your question here, yes, you did not scale your data, which is a big nono when it comes to ML, specially with unsupervised learning. Furthermore, I specified that everything other than the most occuring cluster becomes noise, which again hints that eps and nsamples need to be adjusted

Comment: @Larbalette just edited, hope this helps you further in understanding my logic behind the re-definition of the clusters.

Comment: I've just tried by adapting my own code with your idea.
It's working pretty well !
What was key, that you've learned me, is the need for scaling data. That did the difference ! Perfect, thanks @TinoD